# Pass request to every Swig template using Express

Tags: express, swig-template

Is it possible to pass request/req object to every template I render, so I wouldn't have to pass it as local in every render() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) for that.

Insert the following middleware somewhere before your routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.req = req;
  next();
});
```

This exposes `req` as a variable in your templates.